# Google API Analytics - Why View ID in URI is other than my ViewID?

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api

My View id is 12345678. And I see on this website:
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

My View id in URL is other (like a%3A88220140 ) (look below)

I am talking about this URI: (Query Explorer)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A88220140&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=2020-07-05&metrics=ga%3Ausers%2Cga%3AnewUsers%2Cga%3Asessions%2Cga%3AbounceRate%2Cga%3AavgSessionDuration%2Cga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3ApageviewsPerSession&access_token=".$TOKEN_URL
```

How I can hash this view id to pass to link? Which method I can use? I used PHP.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many inbuilt functions that you can use to hash your value.

- [hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)
- [sha1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)
- [md5](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)
- [crypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) -> ...This is a one way string hashing method mostly used to store passwords....

These are some of the mostly used encryption functions.For further reference you can visit [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.hash.php)